How to use datalist on iOS Safari?
I have an issue about how iOS Safari handles datalist.
The following code works fine on all desktop browsers.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<body>
    <form action="">
        <label>Favorite fruit: </label>
        <input list="fruits" id="fruitsInput" autocomplete='off' autocorrect='off' spellcheck='off'/>
        <datalist id="fruits">
            <option value="Apple">Apple</option>/>
            <option value="Peaches">Peaches</option>/>
            <option value="Pear">Pear</option> />
            <option value="Apricot">Apricot</option> />
            <option value="Banana">Banana</option> />
        </datalist>
        
        <button onclick="datalistcall()" type="button">
            Click Here
        </button>
    </form>

<p id="output"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function datalistcall() {
            var o1 = document.getElementById("fruitsInput").value;
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =
                "You select " + o1 + " option";
        }
    </script>
</body>
 
</html>



It displays a text field which can be filled via a datalist menu. When the button is clicked, the chosen item is displayed.
On iOS Safari, the input field is shown with a small arrow to display the menu and it works fine also.
But the datalist is of course also used to start typing and the browser will usually adjust the menu will corresponding items.
On iOS Safari, no menu is shown but instead the relevant items are display on a line above the keyboard (see image 1).
You can then select an item and.. nothing happens! The item list disappears (see image 2) and nothing changes in the input field and no event is triggered.
Am I missing something or are datalists unusable on iOS safari?



Yes, this used to work, but it appears to be broken for me as well. I click the ones in predictive text and nothing happens. I'm not sure when it broke, but I can recreate it in the simulator, and on the MDN page for datalist. Must be a bug in iOS introduced in a recent version.
https://twitter.com/webtonull/status/1779803326080532804

I’m seeing the same thing. Used to work in my app, which hasn’t changed in months, but no longer works.

It's not perfect, and I'm not sure how you can educate your users on how it works, but did you notice there's a pulldown arrow in your datalist input field? Use the otherwise useless line items (suggestions) above the keyboard as a guide on how far you want to go before pulling the dropdown down to physically select it from there. Bogus workaround, but at least it's one that works.
